# How to sum values of Key value pairs inside a List in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an rdd with Key values inside a list

```
rdd = [('12583', [('536370', 3.75), ('536370', 3.75), ('536370', 3.75)]), 
       ('17850', [('536365', 2.55), ('536365', 3.39), ('536365', 2.75)]), 
       ('13047', [('536367', 1.69), ('536367', 2.1), ('536368', 4.95), ('536368', 4.95), ('536369', 5.95)])]
```

I have to add the Values for each Keys in the list of each record. I tried as bellow but it didn't went thru as mapValues wont allow that addition on lists.

```
newRDD = rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0],list(x[1].mapValues(sum))))
```

My expected results is as bellow

```
[('12583', ('536370', 11.25)), 
('17850', ('536365', 8.39)), 
('13047', ('536367', 3.79),('536368', 9.9), ('536368', 10.9))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a list aggregation function using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
def agg_list(lst):
    from collections import defaultdict
    agg = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
    for k, v in lst:
        agg[k] += v
    return list(agg.items())
```

And then map it over the `rdd`:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0]] + agg_list(x[1])).collect()
# [['12583', ('536370', 11.25)], 
#  ['17850', ('536365', 8.69)], 
#  ['13047', ('536367', 3.79), ('536369', 5.95), ('536368', 9.9)]]
```